# Missing kernel headers, but need them to install the Wifi driver

Tags: kernel, drivers, compiling, kali-linux

I am trying to install Kali on my Lenovo Yoga13, but after formatting the disk the setup failed to install `grub` because of no internet access (no Ethernet, need driver to get Wifi to work).

So, I decided to compile the Wifi driver to complete the setup just to realize I am missing kernel headers. I cannot `apt-get install` because I do not have net access. Is there a way to manually install kernel headers to compile the driver?

Comment: Can use use removable media to transfer from another computer?

Comment: Yes, I can. But the other computer runs Windows and I have no idea about where can I get the deb

Comment: look in `/etc/apt/sources.list` for the location of the repositories. You also have to determine which deb.

Comment: I found the files looking at the "failed to fetch archive" errors and did what you have said in the answer. Works like a charm, thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not on the install media, then you need to get the deb into `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. If it is there then the download part of `apt-get` will be skipped.